# Getting decryption error when decrypting the data string which is encrypted with public key

Tags: java, spring-boot, aes, rsa, private-key

I have a encrypted private key which I have to decrypt using Shared key,which I did and got byte[]. I have converted the byte[] to utf8 string and then converted that string to **Private** key. Now, I have to use this private key to decrypt one time encrypted public key. While doing that, I am getting the following error.

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:370) ~[na:1.8.0_311]
```

This is how I generated private key.

```
 public static PrivateKey decrypt(String stringKey) throws Exception {
    JSONObject jsonKey = new JSONObject(stringKey);

    BigInteger e = new BigInteger( jsonKey.getString("e")); // Public exponent
    BigInteger n = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("n").getBytes());
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("d").getBytes());
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("p").getBytes());
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("q").getBytes());
    BigInteger dmp1 = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("dmp1").getBytes());
    BigInteger dmq1 = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("dmq1").getBytes());
    BigInteger coeff = new BigInteger(jsonKey.getString("coeff").getBytes());


    RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec privateKeySpec = new RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec(n, e, d, p, q, dmp1, dmq1, coeff);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
     PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

    return  privateKey;
}
```

I tried many solutions from the Stack Overflow but nothing worked. I am getting my private key as 2046 bits but when I looked online I found out that it should be 1024 or 2048 bits. Am I generating my Private key wrong? If it is wrong, how should I add two bits to it to make it 2048 bits.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you passing into the stringKey parameter? A public key? A private one?

Comment: Why do you have an encrypted public key? That makes no sense; the whole point of public keys is that they aren't secrets and can be safely exposed. But without knowing exactly what form your JSON element values have (and maybe your environment's default charset) it's impossible to say if and how you are wrong, and obviously you can't post them. Are they all printable chars or not? If yes, are they restricted to either of the base64 alphabets or the hex alphabet? If no, are they all below U+0100 and do they cover most of the range hex 00-FF and is the first below hex 80 or not?

Comment: ... And what is the length of each element? Relatedly, 1024 and 2048 bits (NOT bytes) are common 'sizes' for RSA keys (the 'size' measures only the modulus, which determines the cryptographic strength, not the whole key), but they are not required by most standards (NIST FIPS186 is an exception) and other sizes are widely permitted and sometimes used. @NathanielBlanquel: any object described as a key that has elements named e,n,d,p,q,dmp1,dmq1,coeff pretty much has to be a PKCS1 CRT-form RSA private key.

Comment: @NathanielBlanquel I am passing a utf8 string as parameter. I am doing third party integration in my  application. According to their documentation, I have to get a encrypted private key and have to decrypt using shared key which I already have.  I did as they mentioned, but after decrypting with shared key I got a byte array, I converted that byte array to utf8 string and I am passing that string to the posted method parameter to get a private key and using that private key to decrypt the string(which is encrypted with public key)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sorry, If I didn't post my question correctly, I have a string which is encrypted with public key and I am trying to decrypt that string using my private key.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sorry, I meant to say 2046 bits. I have updated my question.  Is it okay if my private key is 2046 bits? I am unable to decrypt the data with my private key. So I am not sure whether the mistake is with my private key which is 2046 bits or I am doing something wrong when decrypting the string with private key.